# How to Copy data from a txt file to a table present in a schema in a Postgresql database via Python script?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to import data from  txt file to a particular table created inside a schema in a postgresql database.

```js
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='WODR' user='Sam' password='fazilpola'")
print "Connection to database is successful"
cur = conn.cursor()
f= open ("file2.txt")
cur.copy_from(f, meteo_dane, sep = ',') 
f.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Trying the above code now gives me the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 7, in <module>
    cur.copy_from(f, meteo_dane, sep = ',') 
NameError: name 'meteo_dane' is not defined`

Comment: Does that copy command work outside of Python?

Comment: Well ,on checking i found out it actually does not.

Comment: `relation "meteo_dane" does not exist` Is pretty clear: you are connected to the wrong database *OR* the intended schema is not in your schema path *OR* the table does not exist in any of the schemas in your `search_path`.

Comment: I changed a bit in the code and used `copy_from()`. I think the problem is how to deal with the schema and how to define it in the code.

Comment: Ok the problem was that i was not passing the table name `meteo_dane` as str character in the query. So the whole code is `cur.copy_from(f, 'schema.meteo_dane' , sep = ',')  `. Where `schema` was the particular schema where the table was present.